# How to Filter Supported Place Types in Google Maps Nearby Search Requests

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

know Google Maps Api has "school" in its [Supported Place Types list](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) but just wondering if there is a way to add sub list to that list or not? For example, is there any way I can just list the "**Elementary Schools**" instead of all schools in following code?

```
var request = {
location: myplace,
radius: '500',
types: ['Elementary school']
};
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. But most of the elementary school will have the word "elementary" in their name. So, you can filter the result once it is returned by google api.

Comment: Thanks Selvaraj but how I can filter them before displaying on the Map?

Comment: You can try with this api - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=<latitude>,<longitude>&rankby=distance&types=school|church&sensor=false&key=<api_key>